# Finding the information filled in by JavaScript in a {{ }} using Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on searching a webpage for certain text. I've been using the code:

```
import urllib
import re

find = "All others"
pageChecker = urllib.urlopen("192.168.1.134/dashboard").read()
if find in pageChecker:
    print "Search found!"
else:
    print "Search not found"
```

The HTML for the page can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/0sE6GmKa).

This works fine for any text filled in as a paragraph, but the problem is I'm trying to find the information filled in by {{ }}. For example, there is one called

```
{{story.type}}
```

When the webpage is viewed this is shown as a number. How can I figure out what that number is?

Comment: I think you can use if `startswith('{{') and endswith('}}')`

Comment: `re.findall(r'\{\{([^\}]*)\}\}',pageChecker)` returns a list of all fragments of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those curly brackets are for runtime templating. That means you are trying to pull data from a HTML5 application which uses some library like AngularJS, Vue.js, etc. Basically, you have to run the JavaScript to get those placeholders filled.

So there are two solutions here:

1. Use a browser to open the page. That will run the JavaScript code and then you can query that field. You can accomplish this using [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS), SlimerJS, or WebDriver with any browser you want.
2. The JavaScript application itself must get the data from somewhere, most probably from a JSON service. Open your favourite browsers developer console, open the network tab, and navigate to the dashboard. You will see a few requests. Search for the one that contains the information you need, and open that from Python instead of getting the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To find a list of all the items within `{{`s and `}}`s, put `import re` at the start of your program, and then `re.findall(r"\{\{(.*)\}\}", pageChecker)` should give you such a list.